# wpf - add new item to a sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint-2010

I have a form i created on WPF.

after user fill in the custome "form" and click Submit Button

the form will be add to a SharePoint list as an item.

wondering if there is any way i can achieved this??

Answer (score 0):

> the form will be add to a SharePoint list as an item.

One will need to use the [Microsoft.SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint(v=office.14).aspx) libraries which will allow you to manipulate various items within sharepoint to achieve your goal.

Comment: Since this is a client app, they'd almost certainly need to use the client object model, not the server object model, unless the app is going to be a utility app specifically for the site administrators.